# Unable to share dynamic image on Facebook using open graph

Tags: jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc

Dynamic image on Facebook share in not displaying. I am writing this code in index.html page

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="2045440062427669" />
<meta property="og:url" content="@thisUrl">
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:title" content="Cliff Keen Uniform Builder">
<meta property="og:description" content="">
<meta property="og:image" id="ShareImagePath" content="">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="3000">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="10000">
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId: '2045440062427669',
      autoLogAppEvents: true,
      xfbml: true,
      version: 'v2.10'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
      return;
    }
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script
<body>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary fb" onclick="shareOverrideOGMeta('@thisUrl','Cliff Keen Uniform Builder','')"><span><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></span></button>
</body>


I am writting this code on binding.js file


function shareOverrideOGMeta(CurrentUrl, overrideTitle, overrideDescription) {
var OriginalUrl = CurrentUrl.split("&");
console.log('Original Url=', OriginalUrl)
OriginalUrl = OriginalUrl[0];
var CurrentLoggedInUser = sessionStorage.getItem("GetCurrentLoggedInUser");
overrideDescription = "Created on the CliffKeen Athletic Uniform Builder by \"" + CurrentLoggedInUser + "\"";
console.log("value=" + sessionStorage.getItem("CurrentPathOfImage"))
```

This is the code for getting dynamic path

```js
  var path = sessionStorage.getItem("CurrentPathOfImage")
  FB.ui({
    method: 'share_open_graph',
    action_type: 'og.likes',
    action_properties: JSON.stringify({
      object: {
        'og:url': OriginalUrl,
        'og:title': overrideTitle,
        'og:description': overrideDescription,
        'og:image': path
      }
    })
  }, function(response) {});
}
```

At first time I got this error message

> Object Missing a Required Value: Object at URL "http://ub.cliffkeen.com/builder?design=36221cc4-f0b1-4a18-b166-17452d340ff1" 
>   of type "article" is invalid because a required property "og:image:url" of type "url" was not provided.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic OG Tags are not possible anymore, you need to provide the OG Tags in the page source. Check out the docs about possible parameters: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog